# Spam emails appears in exim queue but no email users for this domain

Tags: exim

I have a VPS (example.ru) with multiple sites. To send mail I use an exim 4.76. All domains configured in bind9. Emails delivers by another server (pdd.yandex.ru) for several domains. For example:

`onesite.ru has mx record as mx.yandex.net`

And another site has mx record to my IP [here is bind config](http://pastebin.com/qvaHbE2d).
Here is [exim4.conf](http://pastebin.com/gatkLZ5r). The problem is that for `anothersite.ru` no mail users. Nor in /etc/exim4/passwd nor in /etc/exim4/aliases but from this domain in exim queue appears spam emails. Here is example of [mainlog](http://pastebin.com/fJTYkWxp) and email [headers](http://pastebin.com/vvAbmKqn).

So I would like to know how this emails appear in queue if for this domain is no email users (I'm hacked?) and how to prevent this? Thanks in advance!